# Proper ideal of Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am confused by the statement of a Lemma in Marcus's Number Fields on page 40:

Lemma 2. Let $A$ be a proper ideal in a Dedekind domain $R$ with field of fractions $K$. Then there is an element $\gamma\in K-R$ such that $\gamma A\subseteq R$.

Since $R$ is a proper ideal of $K$, $1\in K-R$. So then $1A=A\subseteq R$. Am I missing something?

Comment: $K$ is a field, so it has no proper ideals.  So your phrase "$R$ is a proper ideal of $K$" is not correct.

Comment: $R$ is the dedekind domain, not the ideal.

Comment: For a non-zero ideal in a Dedekind domain there is a non-zero ideal such that $AB=(c)$ is principal, thus $\gamma A\subset R$ iff $\gamma \in c^{-1}B$. Can you finish from there ?

Comment: Well, $1\in R$, so $1\notin K\setminus R$.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is a nonfield domain, it is *never* an ideal in its field of fractions $K$, because they share identities (by construction.)

So the line

> Since $R$ is a proper ideal of $K$, $1\in K-R$.

contains at least two major errors.